# Layout in Android Emulator looks different as compared to the layout file

Tags: android-studio, xml-layout

I have recently started learning Android Development. I am using Android Studio and I created the XML layout file with it. But the layout is looking different on the emulator to the one I created on XML and I have no clue why it is happening.

This is the picture of my Main activity layout:

[image: img_mail_layout]

And this is the picture of my emulator:

[image: img_emulator]

The plain text should be below the text view but in the emulator, its position is different(I have marked the error by red).

Here is the code for the Main activity:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="208dp"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Enter the value in kg below"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="100dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp" />
```

Comment: This is quite a common Mistake when it comes to using constraint layouts if  you don't constrain your views they will be rendered at the top left corner your EditText(editTextNumber) doesn't have any constraints so it's placed in the top left corner of the screen adding constraints to the EditText should solve this issue

Comment: Also using absolute positions for the views will make the UI of the app inconsistent in devices with different screen sizes

Comment: I think `Infer Constraints` can help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it is showing that way in the emulator versus the preview, but the reason that the EditText field isn't where you want it to be is because of how you have set the position of the `editTextNumber` field:

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="100dp" 
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp"
```

You are telling Android to position the field 100 pixels in and 73 pixels down from the top of the screen. Most than likely this occurred because you accidentally dragged the field slightly in the editor window, which specifies the exact pixel placement.

Instead, since you are using a ConstraintLayout, you'll want to set the location of the EditText in relation to other fields on your layout. For example, remove the two lines above and replace them with something like this:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
```

I would also suggest that you name your fields on the layout with descriptions of what they represent, rather than the defaults of `textView` and `textView2`. For example, consider changing `textView2` to something like `weight_label_textview`. It will make it much easier to know which field you are dealing with both in the layout and in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using constraint layout every UI item must constraint vertical and horizontally. Try adding constraints to your EditText.